# nagios-cgi password screen bypass

Tags: bash, ubuntu, automation, passwords

I am trying to set up a bash script to install nagios3 and all of its dependencies. i understand that:

```
apt-get install -y nagios3
```

takes care of all of that.

what now what im worried about is bypassing the setup screens for nagios3-cgi
i have this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

PASS="0"
REPASS="1"
while [ $PASS != $REPASS ]; do
    read -s -p "Password: " PASS; echo
    read -s -p "Retype: " REPASS; echo
done

debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailname string your.hostname.com"
debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'"
apt-get install -y postfix

apt-get install -y  nagios3
```

i was able to bypass the postfix conf screen with this:

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailname string your.hostname.com"
debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'"
```

how can i do the same thing with nagios3-cgi?

i tried this but it didnt work:

```
mkdir /etc/nagios3
htpasswd -cb /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin $PASS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question.

first i did a normal install of nagios3 on a vm
then i used

```
debconf-get-selections > file.txt
debconf-get-selections >> file.txt
```

this writes all the installation details to file.txt

then search the file for the nagios3-cgi configuration

i found that the name of the config files i needed were

```
nagios3-cgi nagios3-cgi/adminpassword
```

and

```
nagios3-cgi nagios3-cgi/adminpassword-retype
```

then i did the same thing i did with the posfix install.
this was my final script. really simple.

```
PASS="0"
REPASS="1"


#Password loop
while [ $PASS != $REPASS ]; do
    read -s -p "Nagios Password: " PASS; echo
    read -s -p "Retype Nagios Password: " REPASS; echo
done

sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailname string diggalabs.com"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "nagios3-cgi nagios3/adminpassword string $PASS"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "nagios3-cgi nagios3/adminpassword-repeat string $PASS"


sudo apt-get install -y nagios3
```